# How to specify number of packets to ping?

Tags: perl, ping, poe

I'm using [POE::Component::Client::Ping](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Component::Client::Ping) to ping multiple hosts with this [example](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/Pinging_Multiple_Hosts).

As I understand this sends one request to host. Is it possible to specify number of packets to ping like in `ping -c 4 HOST`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to send a ping with a non-standard payload size. 
Details here :

https://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Component::Client::Ping#OTHER-RESOURCES

Comment: thanks, but I can't find there anything about number of packets

Comment: Read the section marked with the subheading - **Payload => $bytes**

Comment: It seems the module you're using is more of a client than a simple command. Does the simpler Net::Ping help? http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Ping.html

Comment: I have to ping 1500 hosts at once so I shifted to asynchronous way.

Comment: @manpreetbhamba Payload or data bytes stands for bytes in packet, so thus one can control packet size. But how can exactly send 4 packets, for example?

Answer (score 0):

No, POE::Component::Client::Ping doesn't implement repetition logic.  It just pings.  I wrote it such that control of *how* it pings is almost entirely in your hands.